# Property [model_b] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance. Laravel/Eloquent hasMany model where clause doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

This is my model

```
class ModelA extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function model_b()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ModelB::class);
    }


}
```

This query works well.

```
$lastWeek = ModelA::find(1)
                                    ->model_b->get();
```

When I am using where clause query

```
$lastWeek = ModelA::where('name','=',$name)
                                    ->model_b->get();
```

It says:

> Property [model_b] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

Answer (score 0):

In your first query, `find()` returns the model, so you are able to access the relation. I think the `->get()` in that instance doesn't do anything.

In your last query, the `where` clause doesn't return the model (its returning the eloquent builder) before you try and access its relation. You could use `firstWhere()`, so that it would be

```php
$lastWeek = ModelA::firstWhere('name', $name)
   ->model_b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
$lastWeek = ModelA::where('name','=',$name)
    ->with('model_b')
    ->get();
$lastWeek = $lastWeek->model_b;
```